# Constant Network Error on BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Phone

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, phone, smartphone

I am recurrently getting "Network Error" on my BQ Ubuntu Phone. I'm still connected to the wifi according to the indicator, and most of the time it starts working if I refresh the page a few times.

This happens in all apps that connect to the internet. Sometimes I go to the web browser to refresh before I go back to the app because this seems to work better for me.

I haven't used my Ubuntu Phone for a few months. I don't remember having this problem back then so it seems to be caused by a "recent" update.

Is this a bug that more people are experiencing? Where can I +1 to the bug or report it if there is no bug report filed?

**Update 1**: It no longer works to just refresh the page. I have to reconnect to the wifi. After I reconnect it works for a few seconds and then stops working again and I have to repeat the procedure.

**Update 2**: I was mistaken. I can still refresh until it starts working again. But it takes 10-20 refreshes before it connects and takes me to the webpage.

Comment: It this behavior limited to one wi-fi spot or have you tryied various networks?

Comment: It is multiple networks.

Comment: Similar problems here with a Nexus 4 OTA-8.5. Did you report the issue?